# embed header and footer in all html page using google sitebricks @embed

Tags: java, html, embed, guice, sitebricks

I am building an Admin dashboard with google guice and sitebricks .Can you please tell me how to include other html files in a html page ? I am looking for a function similar to php's include("header.html") function . I see that sitebricks has an @embed annotation but couldnt find much help about it

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have different possibilities.

**Use embed**

The @Embed annotation allows you to declare pages fragment that can be embed into other pages.

You'll find a full example here : http://code.google.com/p/google-sitebricks/wiki/EmbeddingBricks

**Use decoration**

The other approach is to decalre a generic page with your header and footer and use the @Decorated annotation on the container div of your page.

Then you have to declare all pages as @Decorated and extends the generic page.

Please find more documentation in sitebricks google group : https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/google-sitebricks/decorated/google-sitebricks/CUOJM-CP9hM/ENe930RAuZwJ

Answer (score 0):

Please check the examples at site-bricks site and let us know if they help.
http://code.google.com/p/google-sitebricks/source/browse/trunk/acceptance-test/src/main/java/com/google/sitebricks/example/?r=146

Comment: Not really .I need a little more specific example . I see an example called embed.java but i need a clear example of embedding one html page in another .